# Difference in Python class declaration

Tags: python, python-2.6

In python class declaration I can declare a class by few ways. What is a difference between following samples?

```
class MyClass:
 def __init__(self)
     pass


class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self)
     pass
```

Comment: An important question, but one that could have obviously been answered 'self-serve' by reading the docs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way creates a "new-style" class. Documentation is admittedly a bit lacking, as mentioned in a couple places on the python website [Python Guide 3.3](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), and [here](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/). There's also an [essay](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) describing their design by Python's creator (Guido van Rossum), but it's not strictly documentation.

Answer (score 7):

The second declaration creates a [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle). A new-style class is derived from a built-in type, in this case an `object`. This was introduced in python 2.2 in an effort to unify classes and types. For backward compatibility *old-style* classes are still the default

Additional read: http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/sect-rellinks.html

Comment: FTR, in Python 3 there is no difference between these 2 syntaxes.